# Custom paging query cannot return Page<T> type?

Tags: spring-data-jdbc

[official document#jdbc.query-methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#jdbc.query-methods)

```
List<Person> findByFirstnameOrderByLastname(String firstname, Pageable pageable);
```

If you change the return type from List to Page, an error will occur. Is there any solution?

I can think of adding `count()` method, and then calling `PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(...)` to get the result. I don't want to write a `count()` method.

Answer (score 1):

`Page` and `Slice` currently aren't supported as return types.

The workaround you hint at it the recommended way to do it currently: Return a list, have a separate count-query and combine the results into a `Page` using `PageableExecutionUtils.getPage`.

Anybody interested in this feature might want to watch [DATAJDBC-554](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-554).